# Edit CSV file with Python

Tags: python, string, csv, edit

I have a CSV that looks like this

```
"String1","variablelengthstring1","No"
"String2","variablelengthstring2","No"
```

String1 and string2 does NOT contain the characters `"` or `,`

variablelengthstring1 and variablelengthstring2 does NOT contain the characters `"` or `,`

The output file should look like this

```
String1 variablelengthstring1
String2 variablelengthstring2
```

So I want to remove the last 6 chars on each line, i.e.
`","No"`

Then, I want to remove all `"` from the file

Then, I want to replace all `,` with a space

That should safely accomplish what I am trying to do

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just create a program that reads the file line by line, splitting each line up with `.split(',')`, removing all `"`s from the string, then printing the first parts. Like this:

```
with open('test.csv') as csv:
    for row in csv.readlines():
        cols = [s.replace('"', '') for s in row.split(',')]
        print(cols[0], cols[1])
```

If you need to output it to a file, then you can use redirection in your command line. Just run the program like this:

```
python program.py > output.txt
```

Alternatively, you can use another nested `with` statement and `.writelines()`, like this:

```
lines = []
with open('test.csv') as csv:
    for row in csv.readlines():
        cols = [s.replace('"', '') for s in row.split(',')]
        lines.append(f'{cols[0]} {cols[1]}\n')

with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Shouldn't depend on console redirection to write it back to a file, should just write it directly. Otherwise yes this works fine.

Comment: @kjsmita6 I've updated my answer with an alternative example of writing the lines directly to a file. It should be all good now.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. can I arrange in decending order by numerical value of variablelengthstring1

Comment: @investome If you need to rearrange the output, then you'll want to first read the CSV into a list, then use the `.sort()` method. If you need more help with that, you might want to ask another question.